# When I try to break a block it opens the game menu

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Every time I go to break a block in Minecraft it opens the in-game menu.

I don't know how to stop this from happening, any ideas?

Comment: Check your key bindings. You may have bound the menu to the mouse button. Reset your bindings to default.

Comment: Please include more detailed specifications of your computer. Sometimes, touchpad drivers can cause strange things to happen.

Comment: does it happen when you point at the sky and click the mouse button as well or only when you try to break a block?

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at your controls, I think that you have it so that if you left-click it opens the menu instead of Esc.

Answer (score -4):

It's a Java bug. Try downloading and installing a different (newer, older, whatever) Java VM. As a workaround, hit more slowly, one click at a time. The bug seems to trigger when you hold the mouse button down for repeated clicks.

Comment: How does one "hit more slowly, one click at a time"? When you release the mouse, you're no longer hitting and any damage done is undone..

Comment: I don't believe you. I think what you're describing is a LWJGL bug were the mouse-pointer becomes visible because of clicking.

Comment: This answer makes me question whether you play this game.